# LLN when $E X = \infty$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, law-of-large-numbers

> Does there exist a random variable $X$ with $\mathbb{E}X = \infty$ and some constants $a_n \to \infty$ such that if $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ are iid $\sim X$, then
>   $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_n}{a_n} \to Z$$
>   for some non-trivial random variable $Z$, i.e. $Z \in (0,\infty)$? (Choose your favorite mode of convergence: distribution, probability, almost sure.)

I suspect this is impossible. Can we prove this? (If I've missed something simple, feel free to suggest an additional assumption that rules out a trivial example or a variant that makes this easier.)

Clearly $Z$ would have to have $\mathbb{E}Z = \infty$, and $a_n$ would satisfy $a_n \gg n$.

One thought is something along the lines of $P(X = n!) = 2^{-n}$ for $n \geq 1$, i.e. where the sum of the $X_i$ is basically equal to the maximum of the $X_i$. Then if the maximum scales 'smoothly' enough, a limit would exist.

A possibly interesting generalization is: what if the $a_n$ are replaced by a different iid (independent of the $X$'s) sequence $Y_n$? Could

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_n}{Y_n}$$

actually exist?

Comment: Why does one "clearly" need $a_n \gg n$?

Comment: It's a pretty well-known variant of the SLLN that if $E[X] = \infty$ then $(X_1 + \dots + X_n)/n$ diverges to $\pm \infty$ a.s.  So by multiplying and dividing by $a_n$ we see that in order to have any hope of getting the conclusion, we must have $n/a_n \to 0$.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Durrett's *Probability: Theory and Examples*, Example 2.2.7 describes the    "St. Petersburg Lottery": Let $T \sim \mathrm{Geo}(1/2)$ and let $X = 2^T$.  It is easy to check that $E[X] = \infty$.  If $X_1, X_2, \dots$ are iid with the same distribution as $X$, and $S_n = X_1 + \dots + X_n$, he shows in Example 2.2.7 that $S_n / (n \log_2 n) \to 1$ in probability.

On the other hand, Durrett's Theorem 2.5.9  (due to Feller) states that whenever $E|X| = \infty$, there cannot exist any sequence $a_n$ such that $S_n / a_n$ converges a.s. to a finite nonzero limit. In fact, $\limsup S_n/a_n$ is either identically zero or identically $\infty$.  So you cannot strengthen "in probability" to "almost surely".

Comment: This is what I was looking for! So any $X$ with $EX = \infty$ is too poorly behaved to hope for a.s. convergence.

Answer (score 2):

You can take $a_n = n^2$ and $X_1,\dots, X_n,\dots$ to be i.i.d. [Lévy r.v.'s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy_distribution).

Then
$$
\mathbb{E}[X_i] = \infty
$$
but
$$
\frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{k=1}^n X_k \stackrel{d}{=} X_1
$$
(Note that the Lévy distribution is [1/2-stable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distribution), which explains the latter property.)